# Select only <a> inside div with js

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I select the 1st a in this code with JavaScript? (href=some.php)

```
<div class="accordionButton"><div id="acr_btn_title"><a href="some.php"><p>stuff</p></a></div><div class="hn_little_box"></div></div>
            <div class="accordionContent" >
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="page_01">Page 01</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page_02">Page 02</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page_03">Page 03</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
```

I want to make it so when that `<a>` is clicked, the JavaScript doesn't execute. This is for an accordion side nav, so when it's clicked the accordion doesn't expand, but still tells the browser to go to that page.

**I'm thinking something like this:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#acr_btn_title a').click(function() {
      return false;
  });
  </script>
```

but this stops the link from working. 
**I just want the JavaScript to stop, not stop the `<a>` from functioning!**

[image]

Comment: why is this down voted...what did I do wrong?

Comment: I believe the reason why you've received some down votes is because "*selecting the first element with jquery*" is something that should take a single google search.

Comment: thanks, perhaps I should've made the last sentence stand out more. I hate when people don't read the entire post.

Comment: To be fair, `the javascript doesn't execute` is not very describing. Is there some other javascript assigned to the `<a>` element, or what do you mean with "want the javascript to stop"? Just don't add it?

Comment: I don't want the nav to expand when the <a> is clicked. I just want the browser to go to that page, without dropping down.  So when the <a> is clicked, no the javascript returns false, but the <a> continues to work

Comment: Why do you have an accordian implemented if you want to stop it doing its thing when the links are clicked?

Comment: What does that have to do with "*Select only <a> inside div with js*"? What you want is the third piece of code in my answer, though.

Comment: because the accordion's top tier is 2 divs side by side - the left div is the title. Clicking that should take you to a separate page. The right div is a 'drop down arrow' clicking that drops the accordion down.

Comment: @nnnnnn My *guess* is that it's a plugin that styles **and** adds JS functionality to elements with the `#accordionButton` class, and the OP doesn't want to change the CSS file. It doesn't explain why the JS file couldn't just be left out, though. Maybe it's a part of a framework such as jQueryUI?

Comment: @h2ooooooo No, that's not the case. I'll post an image of what I have.

Comment: Ok I added an image, I hope this clears up my terrible ambiguity.

Comment: there. my answers is at the bottom. I needed to select the a with JS, then stopPropagation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're very close, but if you only want the first one, use the [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) selector:

```
$('#acr_btn_title a:first').click(function() { 
    return false; 
});
```

---

I'd suggest you use [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) and [`stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation) instead of `return false`, though:

```
$('#acr_btn_title a:first').click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

---

Do take note that you **cannot** make sure that a javascript is called when clicking a link. What you can do though, is add the link logic to the `click` event, but prevent the default:

```
$('#acr_btn_title a:first').click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    //Your javascript goes here

    location.href = $(this).prop('href');
});
```

---

You can also place the accordion logic (if you control it) on anything **but** the first one using [`gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/):

```
$('#acr_btn_title a:gt(0)').accordionPlugin();
```

or refer to `a` elements with the `href` attribute **not** set to eg. `#`:

```
$('#acr_btn_title a[href!=#]').accordionPlugin();
```

Comment: The only thing I need with this is the <a> doesn't fire. Nothing happens...I still the browser to go to the link...just no execute the JS that normally follows!

Comment: your answer wasn't spot-on but it did lead it being solved. What I needed was `<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#acr_btn_title a').click(function(e) {
 
 e.stopPropagation();
   
});
  </script>` it's a hard question to ask without posting the entire JS function, ya know? I wasn't even sure what my problem was, so I didn't know how to ask my question. It's hard to ask little question when you're not sure exactly what your problem is. Any better ideas on a title? I was trying to just select the <a> and ignore the JS, not have it be so when the <a> is clicked the JS stops firing.

Comment: I still don't think I needed any down votes, if people read my post they'd see I did my research, was clear in what I was looking for, and  I posted my code. They could've at least made a suggestion or let me know why they voted down, instead of being distant silent Internet judges of proper questions feeling holier than thou handing out down votes self proclaimed syntax grammar police spending 4 seconds on a question

Answer (score -2):

Since you are using jQuery, try `$($("#acr_btn_title a")[0])`

Comment: Why would you do double selectors? If it's because of "alternate solutions" then `$("#acr_btn_title a:last").parent().find("a:eq(0)")` would also return the correct element, but is, once again, just a silly workaround.

Comment: Because [0] returns a DOMElement, not a jQuery object.

Comment: Yet `:eq(0)` or `:first` returns a direct jQuery element - no reason to make it harder for yourself.

Comment: It's simply the first way that came to mind for me, not a workaround. Maybe it isn't the most elegant way to solve the problem.